# Duplicação de valores ao importar arquivo .csv quando falta uma ou mais coluna(s) no arquivo

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Quando importo um arquivo .csv para salvar no banco de dados e no arquivo esta faltando o nome de alguma coluna ao invés de inserir *null* no banco ele repete o valor da primeira coluna.

Segue exemplo;

```
$sourcePath = $_FILES['fileTabelaTeste']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "/pages/dados/".$_FILES['fileTabelaTeste']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath);
$abraArq = fopen("/pages/dados/".$_FILES['fileTabelaTeste']['name']."","r");


    $fieldnames = fgetcsv($abraArq, 5000, ',');

    $idx_prod_codigo = array_search("prod_codigo", $fieldnames);
    $idx_prod_descricao = array_search("prod_descricao", $fieldnames);
    $idx_prod_site = array_search("prod_site", $fieldnames);
    $idx_prod_peso_bruto = array_search("prod_peso_bruto", $fieldnames);
    $idx_und_codigo = array_search("und_codigo", $fieldnames);

    while ($row = fgetcsv($abraArq , 4096, ',')) {
        $prod_codigo = $row[$idx_prod_codigo];
        $prod_descricao = $row[$idx_prod_descricao];
        $prod_site = $row[$idx_prod_site];          
        $prod_peso_bruto = $row[$idx_prod_peso_bruto];
        $prod_peso_bruto = str_replace(",",".",$prod_peso_bruto);
        $und_codigo = $row[$idx_und_codigo];

     $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO produtosTeste

                (PROD_CODIGO, PROD_DESCRICAO, PROD_SITE, PROD_PESO_BRUTO, UND_CODIGO) values

                ('$prod_codigo','$prod_descricao','$prod_site','$prod_peso_bruto','$und_codigo') ") or die(mysql_error());
     }
```

o arquivo csv vem por um input file, e se neste arquivo, por exemplo, não tiver a coluna und_codigo, insere no banco o mesmo valor de prod_codigo.

Dentro do while depois de atribuir o valor para a variavel `$pro_codigo` atribui null para a `$row[$idx_prod_codigo]`, que era o valor que estava indo para as colunas que deveriam salvar null, e resolveu temporariamente.

Comment: se pode colocar o seu procedimento, o seu código e um exemplo do arquivo?

Comment: Bruno consegue adicionar um exemplo do código que você esta fazendo?

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta com um pedaço do código. Foi mal devia ter colocado antes kkkkk Vlw